# DRF : Custom permission denied message

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, django-permissions

How to change the default **DRF-Permission Denied message** from 
`{"detail":"You do not have permission to perform this action."}` to something like this,

`{"status": False, "message": "You do not have permission to perform this action."}`
I found this [SO Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33241338/8283848), but it doesn't help to change the `Key` for the `message`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To include status to the error response you can write custom [`error handler`](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/exceptions/#custom-exception-handling):

```
from rest_framework.views import exception_handler

def custom_exception_handler(exc, context):
    response = exception_handler(exc, context)

    if response.status_code == 403:
        response.data = {'status': False, 'message': response.data['detail']}

    return response
```

In settings:

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'EXCEPTION_HANDLER': 
'my_project.my_app.utils.custom_exception_handler'
}
```

Answer (score 6):

You can create a custom permission by extending the `BasePermission` class and use a custom exception with custom `status_code` and `default_detail` to use in that custom permission.

```
class CustomForbidden(APIException):
    status_code = status.HTTP_403_FORBIDDEN
    default_detail = "custom error message"


class CustomPermission(permissions.BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        if not_allowed:
            raise CustomForbidden
```